# Replace repeated xml tags value using regex

Tags: java, regex

Input -

```
String ipXmlString = "<root>"
        + "<accntNoGrp><accntNo>1234567</accntNo></accntNoGrp>"
        + "<accntNoGrp><accntNo>6663823</accntNo></accntNoGrp>"
        + "</root>";
```

Tried follwing things using to mask values within  using

```
String op = ipXmlString .replaceAll("<accntNo>(.+?)</accntNo>", "######");
```

But above code masks all the values

```
<root><accntNoGrp>######</accntNoGrp><accntNoGrp>######</accntNoGrp></root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root><accntNoGrp><accntNo>#####67</accntNo></accntNoGrp><accntNoGrp><accntNo>#####23</accntNo></accntNoGrp></root>
```

How to achieve this using java regex ?Could someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replacement is wrong, you need to include the `<accntNo>` tag in the actual replacement.  Also, it appears that you want to show the last two characters/numbers of the account number.  In this case, we can capture this information during the match and use it in the replacement.

**Code:**

```
String op = ipXmlString.replaceAll("<accntNo>(?:.+?)(.{2})</accntNo>", "<accntNo>######$1</accntNo>");
```

**Explanation:**

```
<accntNo>     match an opening tag
(?:.+?)       match, but do not capture, anything up until the first
(.{2})        two characters before closing tag (and capture this)
</accntNo>    match a closing tag
```

Note here that by using `?:` inside a parenthesis in the pattern, we tell the regex engine to *not* capture it.  There is no point in capturing anything before the last two characters of the account number because we don't want to us it.

The `$1` quantity in the replacement refers to the first capture group.  In this case, it is the last two characters of the account number.  Hence, we build the replacement string you want this way.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i need to retain the last two values in the output <accntNo>#####67</accntNo>. Sorry for not higlighting

Comment: @vamosa Refresh your page, I have addressed this requirement.  Also check the demo.

Comment: it works as a charm. just trying to understand what $1 does could u pls?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ipXmlString = "<root>"
                + "<accntNoGrp><accntNo>1234567</accntNo></accntNoGrp>"
                + "<accntNoGrp><accntNo>6663823</accntNo></accntNoGrp>"
                + "</root>";
        String replaceAll = ipXmlString.replaceAll("\\d+", "######");
        System.out.println(replaceAll);
    }
```

Prints:

```
<root><accntNoGrp><accntNo>######</accntNo></accntNoGrp><accntNoGrp><accntNo>######</accntNo></accntNoGrp></root>
```